# File cache in gae PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, caching

I'm having some trouble using gae php as a simple proxy using "file_get_contents"

When i load a file for the first time I get the latest version available.
But if I change the content of the file, I dont get the latest version immediately.

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/'.$url);
```

The temporary solution I found was to add a random variable at the end of the query string, which allowed me to get a fresh version of the file every time :

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/'.$url.'?r=' . rand(0, 9999));
```

But this trick doesn't work for api calls with parameters for example.

I tried disabling APC cache in the php.ini of gae (using apc.enabled = "0") and i used `clearstatcache();` in my script, but neither work.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [appengine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/) the http stream wrapper uses `urlfetch`. As [seen in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761557/app-engine-urlfetch-cache-clearing) `urlfetch` provides a public/shared cache and as such does not allow individual apps to clear it. For your own services you can set the HTTP cache headers to reduce or void the cache as necessary.

Additionally, you can also add HTTP request headers indicating the maximum age of data that is allowed to be returned. The python example given in mailing list thread is:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers = {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=300'})
```

Per [php.net file_get_contents http header example](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents#example-2368) and [HTTP header documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) a modified example would be:

```
<?php
$opts = [
  'http' => [
    'method' => 'GET',
    'header' => "Cache-Control: max-age=60\r\n",
  ],
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

Comment: OK, thanks. The cache got cleared by itself after some time but i guess i'll have to set the cache headers from the server then. That's too bad. Is there any other way to achieve this in gae php, other than using urlfetch ?

Comment: Updated response to include fetch example with cache-control header which is an alternative to doing so on the server side, but not that anyone else using your service would need to do so as well or risk stale data.

Comment: That's very cool, I didn't see you could set the header in the request.